# How to recover Ubuntu data if it's installed inside Windows?

Tags: windows, wubi

I want to install Ubuntu inside Windows.

However, if Windows gets corrupted, how can data from the Ubuntu system be recovered?

Comment: = This is a Windows related question/problem and is there for off topic. And I would suggest to backup important data regardless of any possible future problem. = AU expects questions to be about real problems.

Comment: @eliah see the faq? "What kind of questions should I not ask here?

**You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face**. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. "  I can not interpret this in any other way.

Comment: @Rinzwind While I feel pretty sure [this kind of question is on-topic and considered constructive](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3487/questions-just-for-curiosity), *the OP has not provided critically important information about **what situation** the question is about or **what kind of recovery** (e.g., getting the `root.disk` file after filesystem corruption, accessing its contents, or something else altogether)*. So I think it's time to close this as *not a real question*. **DllFileMissing**: If you still want help with this, please provide more information; this could be reopened.

Answer (score 5):

The data can be recovered if Windows is unbootable but you can still access the filesystem. All of the data is stored inside of a filesystem image called `C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`.

Simply boot an Ubuntu livecd, mount the `NTFS` partition and then mount that image (`sudo mount -o loop /path/to/root.disk /mnt`), get to where you mounted it (`/mnt` if you used the above command) and backup your data.

If you cannot mount the `root.disk` and you suspect filesystem corruption, then you should do the following (the order is important):

1. Run `chkdsk /r` from Windows to fix any `NTFS` file system corruption
2. Mount and `fsck` the `root.disk` from a live CD in case there is `ext3/4` corruption

If there is no file system corruption you can also access the `root.disk` from within Windows using [`ext2read`](https://github.com/mregmi/ext2read)

Comment: You're missing an important details. You need to mount the Windows partition that contains the `root.disk` first, and then you need to mount the `root.disk` with the `-o loop` option.

Comment: @bcbc Unless we have another question about this with more answer, you might consider posting an answer here. I mention this so many months later because I've just noticed [a more recent question that's probably a duplicate of this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/527358/22949).

Comment: @EliahKagan ok - I added a bit more info to this answer.