# Accessing Ubuntu Files from a Wubi Installation within Windows

Tags: wubi

Right now I'm dual booting between windows and ubuntu (using Wubi).  How can I grab some files from my Ubuntu root drive within windows?

Comment: I think installing a ext2/3/4 driver is the smaller/easier of two parts of the solution to this. I think the main issue is, how can one mount the SquashFS filesystem (i.e., the rewriteable disk image file in which a Wubi system's filesystem is stored)? That makes this interesting and is one way it differs from [that](http://askubuntu.com/q/9933). I don't know how to do it (or I'd post an answer), [but it looks like it may be possible](http://old.slax.org/forum.php?action=view&parentID=28069). *But what do you need? Could you just boot Ubuntu and copy the files from there (to `/host`)?*

Comment: Well, unfortunately I can't boot to ubuntu anymore: http://askubuntu.com/questions/534488/booting-up-to-grub-screen I'm trying to access the files that I might have lost :(

Comment: The correct solution for your situation, then, is very probably to create a bootable Ubuntu live CD/DVD or live USB in Windows, boot from it, and in the live environment mount the Wubi system's SquashFS filesystem and copy the files you need from it to someplace accessible in your Windows system. Then you can reboot back into Windows and access them. Unfortunately I don't have time right now to locate and provide more info on this but you might be able to find it by searching, and someone else might find a question that covers it, or if not, provide an answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

You would require a ext filesystem driver for windows to access ubuntu files from windows.Download ext2 driver from the below link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately,  I don't think you can. Unless you use a 3rd party program, Windows can only read NTFS, FAT, or FAT32 type drives. Ubuntu is installed on an ext3 or ext4 type drive. This is why Ubuntu is more popular amongst giant businesses, it can use hardware more effectively than any other kernel and operating system.